# Как определить id?

Tags: mysql, yii2, checkbox

Суть такова:
Заходим в голосование, там есть варианты. Выбираем нужные, нажимаем "голосовать". Происходит запись в выбранные варианты.
Вот код модели Poll:

```
class Poll extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'poll';
}
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'description', 'user_id'], 'required'],
        [['description', 'visibility'], 'string'],
        [['user_id', 'open', 'id'], 'integer'],
        [['created'], 'safe'],
        [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'user_id' => 'User ID',
        'visibility' => 'Visibility',
        'open' => 'Poll status',
    ];
}
public static function find()
{
    return new \common\models\query\PollQuery(get_called_class());
}
public static function getAll()
{
    $data = self::find()->all();
    return $data;
}
public static function getOne($id)
{
    $data = self::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    return $data;
}
```

Вот код модели Vote:

```
class Vote extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'vote';
}
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['poll_id', 'var'], 'required'],
        [['poll_id', 'count', 'id'], 'integer'],
        [['var'], 'string'],
        [['created'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'poll_id' => 'Poll ID',
        'var' => 'Var',
    ];
}
public static function find()
{
    return new \common\models\query\VoteQuery(get_called_class());
}
public static function getAll()
{
    $data = self::find()->all();
    return $data;
}
public static function getOne($idv)
{
    $data = self::find()->where(['id' => $idv])->one();
    return $data;
}
public static function getVotes($poll_id)
{
    $data = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->all();
    return $data;
}
}
```

Это контроллер:

```
public function actionPoll($id, $poll_id, $idv)
{
    $single = Poll::getOne($id);
    $vote = Vote::getVotes($poll_id);
    $vote1 = Vote::getOne($idv);

        if ($vote1->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($vote1->count) {
                $vote1->updateCounters(['count' => 1]);
            }

        return $this->redirect("/site/poll/?id=$single->id&poll_id=$single->id");
    }

    return render('poll', ['single' => $single, 'vote' => $vote,]);

}
```

Структура таблицы poll http://joxi.ru/Y2L4DxKCGyvQ26 ,
структура таблицы vote http://joxi.ru/brRjnNQtk588r1 .
При попытке зайти в голосование, пишет Missing required parameters: idv , я в ссылку добавляю этот параметр, но какое значение ему присвоить ? И правильно ли я пытаюсь определить выбранный вариант ?

Comment: Путаница у вас полная, если честно )) Добавьте в вопрос структуру базы, и код классов Vote и Poll (если там не сильно много конечно) -- разберемся вместе

Comment: @MaximKorshunov я добавил, если что еще нужно выложить, то скажите.

Comment: Оффтоп конечно, но что такое интересное делается в `return new \common\models\query\<Vote|Poll>Query(get_called_class());`?

Comment: @MaximKorshunov , это когда я генерировал модель через gii, там была галочка  Generate ActiveQuery для ActiveRecord class, вот я и сгенерировал. Это как я понял, что-то для вызова классов, но как оно работает я не знаю. В моей работе не используется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто приведу свой вариант реализации. Но в нём также нет защиты от повторного голосования (чтобы не усложнять), зато есть проверка прав доступа, голосовать могут только авторизованные пользователи (просто для демонстрации, уберите если не нужно).

Рекомендую в дальнейшем action `cast-a-vote` перевести на AJAX.

Да, еще, сейчас обратил внимание что у вас в вопросе указано что пользоваьель может выбирать несколько вариантов ответа -- этого я тоже не учел, но это должно быть не сложно.

*models/Poll.php*:

```
/**
 * Опрос
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $description
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $created
 * @property string $visibility
 * @property boolean $open
 *
 * @property PollOption[] $options
 */
class Poll extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'poll';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'description', 'user_id'], 'required'],
            [['description', 'visibility'], 'string'],
            [['user_id', 'open', 'id'], 'integer'],
            [['created'], 'safe'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'visibility' => 'Visibility',
            'open' => 'Poll status',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PollOption::className(), ['id' => 'poll_id']);
    }
}
```

*models/PollOption.php*

```
/**
 * Вариант ответа для опроса
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $created
 *
 * @property integer $poll_id
 * @property string $var текст варианта
 * @property integer $count счетчик голосов за данный вариант ответа
 *
 * @property Poll $poll
 */
class PollOption extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'vote'; // эту таблиу я бы переименовал в poll_option
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['poll_id', 'var'], 'required'],
            [['poll_id', 'count', 'id'], 'integer'],
            [['var'], 'string'],
            [['created'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'poll_id' => 'Poll ID',
            'var' => 'Var',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPoll()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Poll::className(), ['id' => 'poll_id']);
    }
}
```

*controllers/PollsController.php*

```
class PollsController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?', '@'],
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view']
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                        'actions' => ['cast-a-vote']
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Перечень доступных опросов
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $polls = Poll::find()->all();

        return $this->render('index', $polls);
    }

    /**
     * Страница опроса
     *
     * @param $poll_id
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionView($poll_id)
    {
        $poll = Poll::findOne($poll_id);

        if (empty($poll)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Опрос не найден: %d', $poll_id));
        }

        return $this->render('view', $poll);
    }

    /**
     * Голосование за вариант ответа
     *
     * @param $poll_id
     * @param $option_id
     * @return \yii\web\Response
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionCastAVote($poll_id, $option_id)
    {
        $poll = Poll::findOne($poll_id);

        if (empty($poll)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Опрос не найден: %d', $poll_id));
        }

        $option = $poll->getOptions()
            ->where(['id' => $option_id])
            ->one();

        if (empty($option)) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException(
                sprintf('Среди вариантов ответа опроса %d нет варианта за запрошенным ID: ', $poll_id, $option_id)
            );
        }

        $option->updateCounters(['count' => 1]);
        $option->save();

        if (!\Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return $this->redirect(['polls/view', 'poll_id' => $poll->id]); 
        }
    }
}
```

*config/web.php* (если используете шаблон basic)

```
'components' =>
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'GET    polls/<poll_id:\d+>/cast-a-vote/<option_id:\d+>' => 'polls/cast-a-vote',
            'GET    polls/<poll_id:\d+>' => 'polls/view',
            'GET    polls' => 'polls/index',
```

Comment: а 'rules' куда именно в web.php вписать нужно ? И для cast-a-vote ведь нужно вью файл создать ?

Comment: @AlexeyDunin обновил ответ -- добавил куда в `web.php` нужно `rules` писать. Отдельную вьюху для `cas-a-vote` не надо, там же редирект в конце, более того добавил чтобы редиректа не было, если вызов через AJAX сделан

Comment: у меня получилось запустить ваш код, все хорошо работает. Но есть вопрос, как голосовать по кнопке ? То есть если я в адресной строке наберу http://poll.ua/site/cast-a-vote?poll_id=6&option_id=10 (локалка), то оно проголосует и редиерктнит. Но если же я просто выберу чекбокс и нажму кнопку, то страница обновится, но ничего не произойдет.

Comment: @AlexeyDunin чтобы разобраться, нужно посмотреть код формы на которой у вас чекбокс. Раз у вас просто обновляется страница, то скорее всего у вас не верно прописан `action` (или совсем не прописан). Еще, если форма у вас отправляется методом `POST` то это тоже нужно учесть в контроллере, т.к. сейчас `$poll_id` и `$option_id` берутся из параметров `GET`

Comment: У меня получилось, все работает. Я с формой там еще понаделал, сначала голосовало только за последний вариант, потом вообще не голосовало. Но методом проб и ошибок все заработало. Еще так и не понял как средствами yii2 сдлеать поле такого вида `<input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="<?= $item1->poll_id ?>">` , потому использовал обычные поля. Так же проблема была в том, что у меня foreach был внутри формы, а нужно было форму внутрь foreach упаковать, ну и экшен для формы дописать и указать метод get. Теперь голосует. Спасибо вам за помощь!